# laravel: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\CustomException::report() must be an instance of Exception,

Tags: laravel, php-7.1, laravel-5.5, laravel-exceptions

I have created a custom exception class in Laravel 5.2. It works well till laravel 5.4.

When Im trying to use the same **custom exception** class with laravel 5.5 it is throwing following error.

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Utility\Exceptions\CustomException::report() must be an instance of Exception, none given, called in /var/www/html/bubbles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 102 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\\Utility\\Exceptions\\CustomException::report() must be an instance of Exception, none given, called in /var/www/html/bubbles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 102 at /var/www/html/bubbles/app/Utility/Exceptions/CustomException.php:39)
```

Here is the custom exception class I've been using

```
<?php 

namespace App\Utility\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Exception;


class CustomException extends Exception  
{

    private $error_code = NULL;

    private $error_info = NULL;

    function __construct($type = NULL, $errors = NULL)
    {
        $this->error_code = $type['error_code'];
        $this->error_info = $errors;

        $message = Lang::get('exceptions.'.$this->error_code);

        parent::__construct($message, $type['code'], NULL);
    }


    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }


    public function getErrorCode()
    {
        return $this->error_code;
    }


    public function getErrorInfo()
    {
        return $this->error_info;
    }
 }
 // end of class CustomException
 // end of file CustomException.php
```

Could anybody will explain me why it is throwing argument must be instance of exception ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My programming environment
PHP **7.0.1**
Laravel **5.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception handler in Laravel 5.5 checks if the exception has a report method, and if so, let the exception handle the reporting itself. This means that the handler will see your report method, and call `$e->report();`, but your report method requires a parameter.

This is done in [Handler::report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L101-L103).

You either need to remove the parameter in your report method (it should be reporting itself; `$this`) if you want to use this functionality, or rename the method if you don't want Laravel to call it (and fail).

Relevant: [Laravel 5.5 Adds Support for Custom Exception Reporting](https://laravel-news.com/custom-exception-reporting)