# Error whille running composer install on PHP 7.2 Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I kept getting this error at the end of my composer install on PHP 7.2 - Laravel 5.1

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/forge/bheng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in /home/forge/bheng/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/bheng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/forge/bheng/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 29
[2019-01-31 10:29:34] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/forge/bheng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in /home/forge/bheng/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/bheng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/forge/bheng/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  


                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/forge/bheng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in /home/forge/bheng/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:29  
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  #0 /home/forge/bheng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))                                                                                                                                                                     
  #1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  #2 {main}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    thrown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
┌──[root@bheng]──[/home/forge/bheng] 
└──
```

---

## app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
<?php namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;


class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
    'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }



    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
        }
        else if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            return response()->view('missing', [], 404);
        }

        else if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException )
        {
            return response()->view('layouts.share.errors.model_not_found', [], 404);
        }

        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Detail

[image]

---

I've tried those 2 commands

[image]

I still get the same result.

How can I prevent that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel FatalErrorException in Handler.php line 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983734/laravel-fatalerrorexception-in-handler-php-line-25)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516045/laravel-argument-1-passed-to-app-exceptions-customexceptionreport-must-be-a

Comment: What minor version of 5.1 are you using?

Comment: I use this one `"laravel/framework": "5.1.0"`

Comment: Why 5.1.0?  Use the latest 5.1.   `5.1.*`

Comment: let me try update my composer.json and try again.

Comment: Same error when update composer.json to `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*", `

Comment: Can you confirm which version is installed now?  This error should have been fixed when 5.1 introduced support for PHP7.

Comment: How do I confirm ?

Comment: I can't even run `php artisan` : https://i.imgur.com/2qoBmHO.png

Comment: Can you show `App\Exceptions\Handler`?

Comment: @aynber Is it a file path ? I am not sure.

Comment: Show the code from that class.

Comment: @aynber I added it on my post. Now my prod is not working. 

Comment: @Devon Now that I already update to PHP 7, can you please share a steps safely to go back to 5.6 ? If you know how.

Comment: There's no such thing as general steps, every system is different.  It depends how you installed/upgraded PHP and which platform you're on.  I recommend learning some more about PHP and composer before even jumping into Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `composer install --no-scripts` or `composer update --no-scripts` to install / update any packages, and it will skip running any `artisan` commands.

You can then try to run `php artisan clear-compiled` to see if the update has fixed the issue.

If this doesn't work, you should consider upgrading your application to use a newer Laravel version, or downgrade PHP to an older version that is compatible with the version of Laravel you want to use.

Comment: Niraj, I got the same result after running both of your commands, do you know why ?

Comment: The install and update commands are essentially the same. Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: From your new screenshots, it looks like the error has been fixed. `Nothing to install or update` means your packages are all up to date. Then you ran `php artisan clear-compiled`, and your original error wasn't displayed. Does that not mean your problem has been fixed?